# howto do a port forwarding on a windows 2012 server

Tags: port-forwarding, windows-server-2012-r2

Server has 2 network cards: 1) a WAN connection - 2) a LAN connection  - NAT is configured and works - but I want to connect to a particular ip address from the outside using port forwarding - translation - like you do on a simple router ( virtual server setting like for gaming ):

[image]

Did a netsh install but this didn't work - and this doesn't support udp -  I'm testing with the Firewall turned off.

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=my external port  listenaddress=myexternal-ip connectport=my internal port connectaddress=myinternal-ip

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I've been searching for days already and can't figure out how to get it done.